# Html height split to two parts one is changing height and one is Long and scrollable

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to divide a page or a section of the page into two parts (height).
top part will be as much as it's contents height.
bottom part will be the rest of the available height (scrollable if needed).

i made it, and its working, but IE(9) and firefox are showing it badly :(

Maybe i got the wrong idea to start with, maybe no need for table..

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Some Content
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="height:100%">
            <div style="overflow: auto;height: 100%;">
                more long content (scrollable)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Plunkr working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CxTBpvVO93OtQE7kIAra?p=preview)

please help.

--EDIT:

i know there is an easy javascript solution to this problem but I am looking for a pure css html solution.

Comment: When scrolled, do you want the top content is scrolled too ? Or is it only scrolling inside the second content ?

Comment: top should stay in place, bottom should be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your code I believe scrollable meant scrolling only inside the second div. If so, you can use below CSS to divide your page horizontally into 2 parts:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.header{
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.body{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Then to make your the second content to always fill the rest height, you can use below JS:

```
function resize() {
    document.getElementById('body').style.height = '100%';
  var height = document.getElementById('body').offsetHeight - document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById('body').style.height = height + 'px';
};
window.onresize = function(event) {
    resize();
};
window.onload = function(event){
    resize();
}
```

Using below HTML:

```
<body onload="resize()">
<div class="header" id="header">
    HEADER
</div>
<div class="body" id="body">
    <div style="overflow: auto;height: 100%;">
    test<br />
    test<br />
    //it will be scrollable when the content's height > the parent div
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Checkout this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2na2c874/) for more info..

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer but javascript is not an option :( i would have used it already if it was possible, just that javascript onresize changes doesnt work as smooth as css and on page size change it is noticable and slows the rest of the page animations.

Comment: Well, I believe you can't. Except you know the height of the top content, then you can use `calc` which is like this `height: calc(100% - 100px);`

Comment: wow nice, didnt know calc is so well supported IE9+... allmost there only problem is that i dont know the upper part height it is changing.

Comment: That's why you need JS to check/get the upper part height and also use listener to detect the changes.

Comment: As you can see i made it in chrome, in the plunkr demo i put, just missing something for it to work on noober browsers hope someone can help with it.